# Application consumes WCF, does it need to be updated if no calls were updated in app?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I have 2 .NET applications.  And I have a web service that is consumed in both of these applications.

I needed to update one of the method calls in the web service.  The signature changed, which means I would have to update the applications that consume the web service.

My question is, since one of the 2 applications that consumes it calls this particular method and the other application doesn't, do I need to update the web service in the application that does not call this particular method?  Is there a danger in having an "older version" of the web service, or worse, will it just not work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if the server is updated, the client must also be updated. However, if only the internal methods of the service are modified, and the interface is not changed, the client can still call the service normally.

Whether to update the client or not depends on whether the changes of your server will affect the call of the client. If there is an impact, the client must be updated, otherwise the call will fail. I suggest that if the server is updated, it is best to update the client to avoid problems.